# Let $E$ be a subset of a metric space $(S,d)$. Show that if $E$ contains the limit of every convergent sequence contained in $E$, then $E$ is closed

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I am trying to show for a metric space S with distance function d, that if E is a subset of S and E contains the limit of every convergent sequence contained in E, then E is closed.

To start the proof off it seems that I should consider a sequence $s_n$ of points in E that converges to an element in E. Then if I assume that E is open I should find a contradiction, but I am not sure how to proceed.

edit: My working definition of a closed set is that it's complement is open. So It would seem that I would need to show that my premise shows that the complement of E is open(?).

Comment: Do you mean to say "E contains the limit of every convergent sequence contained in E" ?

Comment: Sets are not doors. For example, the empty set and the whole space $S$ are both open and closed.

Comment: @gorzardfu yes edited.

Comment: Don't assume $E$ is open and look for a contradiction.  All that would show is that $E$ is not open, which is not the same as showing that $E$ is closed

Comment: @Aweygan ok so how should I proceed.

Comment: I think you can say that if your convergent sequence converges to a point x in Int(E), the solution is trivial.  Thus, you want to make sure the points on the boundary are in E.  That's just my guess.

Comment: @JamesDickens Try to show that $S\setminus E$ is open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $E$ contains all the limits of the convergent sequences in $E$. Towards a contradiction, suppose that $E$ is not closed. By definition, this means that $S \setminus E$ is not open. Thus there is $x \in S \setminus E$ so that for any $\epsilon > 0$, the ball $B(x,\epsilon) = \{y \in S : d(x,y) < \epsilon \}$ is not contained in $S\setminus E$.  This means that for each $n \in \mathbb N$, we can find $y_n \in E$ so that $d(x,y_n) < \frac 1 n$. However, this clearly implies that $y_n \to x$, so the assumed property implies that $x \in E$. This contradicts the definition of $x$ $($recall, we took $x \in S \setminus E).$ The contradiction implies that $E$ is closed.

Comment: @UserS128 Why can you find a $y_n \in E$ so that $d(x,y_n)<1/n$

Comment: Since $B(x,1/n)$ is not contained in $S\setminus E$, there must be some $$y_n \in B(x,1/n) \cap (S \setminus E)^c = B(x,1/n) \cap E.$$ This $y_n$ is in $E$ and satisfies $d(x,y_n) < 1/n$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in S$ is not in $E$, then no sequence of elements of $E$ can converge to $x$.  That is, there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B_\varepsilon(x)\cap E=\varnothing$ (otherwise we could use $\varepsilon_n=\frac{1}{n}$ to obtain $x_n\in E$ with $d(x,x_n)<\frac{1}{n}$, a contradiction).  Thus $x$ is an interior point of $S\setminus E$.  Since $x\in S\setminus E$ was arbitrary, we know $S\setminus E$ is open, and therefore $E$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your definition of closed, you are forced to show that $S\setminus E$ is open. Everybody else here is showing that proof directly, so I offer a proof by contradiction.

Suppose $S\setminus E$ is not open. There for some $x \in S\setminus E$ and for all $\varepsilon>0$, we know $B_\varepsilon(x) \not\subseteq S\setminus E$. That is, the open ball $B_\varepsilon(x)$ always contains points that are strictly in $E$. Can you use this to construct a sequence of points in $E$ that converge to $x$? Hint: Choose $x_n$ from $B_\frac{1}{n}(x) \cap E$, which we know is always non-empty.